# Check if RHEL certs have been updated

Tags: redhat, ssl-certificate, rhel7

I have a sample .pem file placed in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors`, and I have run `update-ca-trust`, but I'm not sure how I can check if the command actually worked. I tried to cat `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` for the contents of my sample .pem but no luck.

How can I make sure that my certs have been updated?

To downvoters, could you please give suggestions as to what I can elaborate upon to improve my question?

EDIT

Checking  `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt` has also not shown anything, so I will assume that my sample cert was not actually added.

Comment: Try to  run **`update-ca-trust extract`* with the extra option `extract` as that should provide more verbose error reporting.

Comment: @HBruijn Just did that, got no output. Does it create a log file?

Answer (score 3):

Run this command to see what certs are actually inside the CA bundle on the server.

`openssl x509 -text -noout -in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

You can also use the above command, but substitute the path to your added CA cert, to examine the CA certificate you added.